# How to automount a network share once OpenVPN has connected? (Using Tunnelblick)

Tags: macos, vpn, automount, afp

Does anyone know how to automatically mount a network share once a VPN connection using Tunnelblick has connected?

Right now I have to connect and then do a cmd+K in the finder to connect to the AFP share. It'd be nice if it would connect automatically.

The share doesn't have a password (TimeCapsule without any passwords, and no, not using it for backup, we use it for a fileserver).

Answer (score 6):

### 1.

Edit the file `/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.up.osx.sh` and add these commands at the end of the file, just before `exit 0` :

```
su USERNAME -c '
mkdir /Volumes/TimeCapsule
mount_afp afp://afp_username@server/volumename /Volumes/TimeCapsule
'
open /Volumes/TimeCapsule
```

Replace USERNAME with your username on the system.

### 2.

Then add the following at the end of `/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.down.osx.sh` :

```
umount /Volumes/TimeCapsule
```

### 3.

Do not forget to check the `set nameserver` option for your configuration :

[image: nameserver]

***Warning :*** Configuration files `client.(up|down).osx.sh` are executed for every connections made using OpenVPN.

This could also be made using `launchd` for watching if the vpn connection is up, but I don't know how to use launchd.

Comment: Did you forget a line? It isn't working, and when I stick the code directly into Terminal, it asks for my password. Possibly that's why it isn't running in the up script too?

Actually, removing the su line (and it's counterpart ' below) doesn't work either. I would expect it to at least make the dir and possibly connect, but not let me access the folder.

(and yep, set nameserver is checked)

Comment: The `su` command is used to impersonate someone (you in this case). Both scripts are executed as `root` and he doesn't need a password when using `su` but another user will need one. If the command inside `su` isn't working alone, the problem comes from here. What exactly did you type ?

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure that tunnelblick would run it as root.

If I take the command inside of the su and drop it directly into terminal, it runs fine. If I remove the su part and just have the command in the up script, nothing happens.

# Generate an updated plist with the proper path
DIR="$(dirname "${0}")"
LEASE_WATCHER="${DIR}/LeaseWatch.plist"
sed -e "s|\${DIR}|${DIR}|g" "${LEASE_WATCHER}.template" > "${LEASE_WATCHER}"
launchctl load "${LEASE_WATCHER}"
# autoconnect server2


mkdir /Volumes/Data
mount_afp afp://192.168.2.2/Data /Volumes/Data

open /Volumes/Data

exit 0

Answer (score 0):

I have just succeeded to auto-mount NFS after having connected VPN and auto-unmount before discconect with Tunnelblick (3.7.3 on macOS High Sierra).

At first, I had the same problem with Cameron Conner. Still, Studer's answer was quite helpful for me.

Instead of Studer's *client.(up|down).osx.sh*, I placed two lines in the .ovpn:

```
up (path to your connected.sh)
down (path to your pre-disconnect.sh)
```

Then create and edit these **connected.sh** and **pre-disconnect.sh**.

connected.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mkdir /Volumes/NFS
sudo mount -P 192.168.0.1:/share /Volumes/NFS
```

pre-disconnect.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo umount /Volumes/NFS
```

I don't know about TimeCapsule manipulation. So above process is about NFS. I think you can arrange it for TimeCapsule.

I think the point Cameron and I got stucked was su or sudo. And, to avoid password is another problem. My solution to that was **sudoers**.

Edit */etc/sudores* with **visudo**. Modify the %admin entry from:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

to:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Unless your account is not an admin, it should work.